# lan http chat and file shareing

Tags: http, lan, livechat, fileshare

I want to share files and chat over `LAN` using the protocol `HTTP`, the aim is that clients don't have to install anything except of having a browser.
I have tried [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) and edited it to make a very basic chat, the file shareing was fine, but the chat wasn't realtime.
my knowledge doesn't get over `HTML` , `CSS` ,and the very basics of `JS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating such a software needs having knowledge in these languages and tools as it is web based application (HTML, PHP or JSP or .Net, sql server or my sql, Ajax).

***HTML:** to create the GUI (pages, forms, colors).

***Programming languages like PHP or JSP or .Net:** to handel the data transferring (texts and files) and database connection and session creation.

***sql server or mysql**Used to store the data, even if its a real time, you need a database for temporary storing the data.

***Ajax:** its the combination of javascript and css,, it is used to check frequently for new comming messages, for example every 3 seconds..

Comment: thats what I know , what I dont know : is it possible to be established in local area network where my laptop will be the server and other computers are just clients ? and is there a software already made to do so,

Comment: great ! where should i start XD

Comment: This is a simple code, that you can get idea from then make changes depending on requirements and wishes:

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931

Answer (score 1):

This may help..

It is a simple web base live text chat code, that uses php, html, mysql, and ajax

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931